# Text visual appearance in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, user-interface, customization, uipickerview

I have a question about iOS UI customization. I found the built-in picker view has a glass-like cover and the label under the cover has slightly appearance (text with a little inner shadow? such as the "11" and "44" in the attached picture).

[image]

my question is if I want to build something like that from scratch, what direction should I look for? or any tips? :)

Comment: Obviously the shadow is a shadow (white, downwards) and the glass-like cover is a glass-like cover (translucent). Is there a real question here?

Comment: You do know you can change the appearance of the text, right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you may launch the built-in clock or alarm app and try to drag the picker and take a closer look, in the process of dragging, you might find the appearance of the upper half and the lower half of the text is not quite the same. so my question is how can I draw one text with two kinds of appearances?

Comment: Draw two texts, with clipping at the point where they differ.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UIView subclass. You'll be doing a lot of drawing in the drawRect: method. So you will draw line segmements top and bottom, and perhaps two on each side (or an arc). the, then you will use a gradient view, and have it transition from the top to the midpoint using wo values, and from the midpoint to the bottom. If you use "Pixie" you can zoom in on the view and look at various pixel values to guess at starting points.

Later, when you want to use that technique, you will add it as the top subview to whatever it will cover, and set its frame, and it will draw itself when asked to by the system.

You might think of open sourcing this on github - make a name for yourself - and post the code back here. Its up to you.